# Merge 2 associative arrays by matching sub array value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to merge these 2 arrays by the key `aa => "value"`

```
$array1 = array(
    "aa" => array("RM","PR","LE"),
    "bb" => array("100a","200a","300a"),
    "cc" => array("1.99b","2.99b","3.99b")
);
```

The second array may have extra values per key, notice in this example the "ST" value in the "aa" key.

```
$array2 = array(
    "aa" => array("RM","PR","ST","LE"),
    "dd"  => array("UK","UK","UK","UK"),
    "ee" => array("123","456","000","789")
);
```

To end up as 1 array like this.

```
$final_array = array(
    "aa" => array("RM","PR","ST","LE"),
    "bb" => array("100a","200a",null,"300a"),
    "cc" => array("1.99b","2.99b",null,"3.99b")
    "dd"  => array("UK","UK","UK","UK"),
    "ee" => array("123","456","000","789"),
);
```

Resulting with the null values in the repective places. 
It needs to process like a MySQL join, `array_merge()` and `array_merge_recursive()` won't work.
Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not put all column in one row instead ? in your given example you put all rows in one column.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, Can you give me a bit more detail @Eddie?

Comment: You want to put null values? @RMapper

Comment: every time it should come 4 keys in sub array? @RMapper

Comment: @RMapper, I am saying, make array like this `[aa=>RM,bb=>100a,cc=>1.99b,dd=>UK,ee=>123]` this is the right way, not bind the data with position as you given in expected

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$array2` is always greater than `$array1` and the difference on array counts is equal to 1 and the comparison is between the key `'aa'`

```
// Get keys of each array, then merge, then get unique
$all_keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)));
// Get difference of 'aa' then the key
$diff_key = key(array_diff($array2['aa'], $array1['aa']));
// Set `$final_array` as equal to `$array1`
$final_array = $array1;
// Loop thru each keys
foreach ($all_keys as $key) {
    // Check if `$array1` has the key
    if (isset($array1[$key])) {
        // Check if `$array2` also has the key
        if (isset($array2[$key])) {
            // Splice array to add element of `$array2` to final array
            array_splice($final_array[$key], $diff_key, 0, $array2[$key][$diff_key]);
        } else {
            // Splice array to add empty element
            array_splice($final_array[$key], $diff_key, 0, '');
        }
    } else {
        // Add `$array2` element to `$final_array`
        $final_array[$key] = $array2[$key];
    }
}


print_r($final_array);
```

Comment: Hi @Erwin, that's brilliant works perfectly, however, there may be a scenario whereby the "aa" values array could be the same for both $array1 and $array2. How can I give you credit for this, it's a first time for me on stack? Thank you so much.

Comment: Uhm. If that's the case, how can we know where to insert null values? Does it happen to be always on the third element?

Answer (score 0):

try it with your logic

```
$array1 = array(
"aa" => array("RM","PR","LE"),
"bb" => array("100a","200a","300a"),
"cc" => array("1.99b","2.99b","3.99b")
);
$array2 = array(
  "aa" => array("RM","PR","ST","LE"),
  "dd"  => array("UK","UK","UK","UK"),
  "ee" => array("123","456","000","789")
);

 $arr=array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
 $new_arr=array();
 foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
   $new_arr[$key]=array_unique($val);
 }

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: have you test your code UK comes one time only because of array_unique

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$len1 =  count($array1['aa']);
$len2 =  count($array2['aa']);
$final_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $len2; $i++){
  $final_array['aa'][$i] = $array2['aa'][$i];
  if($array2['aa'][$i] != $array1['aa'][$i]){
    $final_array['bb'][$i] = 'null';
    $final_array['cc'][$i] = 'null';
    $final_array['dd'][$i] = $array2['dd'][$i];
    $final_array['ee'][$i] = $array2['ee'][$i];

  }else{
     $final_array['bb'][$i] = $array1['bb'][$i];
     $final_array['cc'][$i] = $array1['cc'][$i];
      $final_array['dd'][$i] = $array2['dd'][$i];
    $final_array['ee'][$i] = $array2['ee'][$i];
  }
  if($array2['aa'][$i] == $array1['aa'][$i-1]){
    $final_array['bb'][$i] = $array1['bb'][$i-1];
    $final_array['cc'][$i] = $array1['cc'][$i-1];
  }
}
print_r($final_array);
```

Check in live demo : https://eval.in/920223

OUTPUT is as :

```
Array
(
    [aa] => Array
        (
            [0] => RM
            [1] => PR
            [2] => ST
            [3] => LE
        )

    [bb] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100a
            [1] => 200a
            [2] => null
            [3] => 300a
        )

    [cc] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.99b
            [1] => 2.99b
            [2] => null
            [3] => 3.99b
        )

    [dd] => Array
        (
            [0] => UK
            [1] => UK
            [2] => UK
            [3] => UK
        )

    [ee] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
            [2] => 000
            [3] => 789
        )

)
```